# Is it possible to call a function in an object that references itself?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
const state = []

const spells = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    channelDuration: 1000,
    castDuration: 1000,
    cast: () => {
     state.push(THIS) // <--
    }
  }, {...}, {...}
]
```

When a player uses a spell, that spell gets stored into the game state and then waits for the `channelDuration` and `castDuration` to pass.

Once able to cast, it looks into the state and calls the `cast` method:

```
State.quest.bossFightState[USER].spell.cast()

state = [Spell]
```

On said cast, i need to push the spell into the a new array called `statuses`. However, i can't reference the object within the cast method without using some additional helper functions to grab the specific spell. And I dont want to pass add a parameter `spell` into the cast method because that just seems dumb.

Any ideas? Or is a helper method the way to go here.

Comment: `state.push(spell)` ??

Comment: So `spells` is actually an array of many different spells. Each has their own cast. The way im handling this in the code is when a user "casts" a spell, it copys the spell and stores it into the state. After a brief channel time, it looks at the stored spell in the state and calls `spell.cast()`

Comment: `const spell = {` is a single identifier, not an array - pushing that single object that the identifier references should work

Comment: Ill update the post with some more info i guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody else caught this... You're using `this` inside of an arrow function. The `this` keyword acts differently in arrow functions - read more about that [here](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc)

```js
const state = [];

const spells = [
    {
        name: 'test',
        cast: function () {
            state.push(this);
        },
    },
];

spells[0].cast();
console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use a `function` or method instead of an arrow function, so that `.cast` will have a `this` referring to the outer object.

```js
const state = []

const spells = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    cast() {
     state.push(this)
    }
  }
]

spells[0].cast();
console.log(state);
```

Comment: Ahh you answered right when the other guy answered haha.